# About loading mongodb in dolphindb under single mode

Tags: mongodb, dolphindb

About loading mongodb in dolphindb under single mode

I load the mongodb plugin in dolphindb under single mode. The code is:

```
res=mongodb::load(conn,`dolphindb:dolphindb,query,option)
```

Then, I get an error:

```
2021.03.10 11:17:43.670: executing code ...
Syntax Error: [line #1] Cannot recognize the token dolphindb
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your string contains a colon, use quotes around a string instead of a backtick.

```py
res=mongodb::load(conn,"dolphindb:dolphindb",query,option)
```